# What is the use of forms.py in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have just started learning django. And when i started a small login system, i had to develop a form for it. I used a html page for it, and processed the data in `views.py` and then put the response in another view. But i came across some file called `forms.py` in the examples given. I don't understand how to use it, which is easy to use and better to use between the two. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Read at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Comment: @Rohan: I can't understand that well. Thats why i posted this question

Comment: Isn't the doc clear enough? You will have to make question clear then.

Comment: You really, really, REALLY need to work through the tutorials on http://djangobook.com/

Comment: @Brandon: Aren't there any other tutorials than django docs and djangobook?

Comment: Google "Django Tutorial". You'll find more than a few tutorials. There are also several books in print to cover everything from the basics to advanced topics, testing and more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`forms.py` (like `admin.py`) is just a convention that is used by django. It is considered best practice but not a strict requirement. There is nothing special or exotic about these files.

`forms.py` is where the django documentation recommends you place all your forms code; to keep your code easily maintainable. Also, since its a convention mentioned in the documentation, it helps when you are collaborating with others because that is where others will expect to look for your code dealing with forms.

Think of it like `index.html`. There is no rule that states that this file should be called `index.html`, but its a convention that has been built over time.

You can have all your [forms classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/) in your `views.py` and nothing will break.  Now if you are not using forms *at all*, and all still processing GET and POST data "manually", this you should stop immediately; especially if it is anything more than search query string.

The only file that is *absolutely required* is `models.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Making models and views "dumb" is by choice: If you use a specific file like "forms.py" where you have your form classes together with their validations, it is much easier and especially faster to unit test these forms than having to use Django's test client. The same goes for models: Any complicated algorithms usually go into a "utils.py" (or similarily named) file, so this can be tested easier.

And lastly, when the size of your views.py or models.py file gets larger and larger over time, it is a bit annoying to scroll around the file all the time.